# Why does a Maven clean (from Eclipse) pull files into the local repository?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I would guess a clean might either delete jars from the repo or leave it untouched. But when I manually deleted the existing repo and then cleaned all the existing projects in Eclipse, the repository was recreated. The problem at least is that it takes a long time. So I am firstly curious as to why this behavior occurs and secondly wonder if there is a way not to have this occur.

Answer (score 0):

The maven install is really little more than a bootstrap. All maven actions are implemented as plugins, downloaded from a Maven repository, and cached in the local repository. This architecture makes Maven extremely extensible (if you know what you're doing).

To improve build performance you are best advised to setup a local Maven repository manager. This will cache jars that would otherwise have to be downloaded from Maven Central.

Running a Maven repository manager is not hard nowadays. It offers the additional features of providing a place to manage dependencies that may not be available from a remote repo and as a place to share jars between different project builds.

Answer (score 0):

The `clean` phase of the `clean` lifecycle *does not* clean your local repository. Instead, it does *"remove all files generated by the previous build"* (in your project's `target` directory, if you use [Maven's Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)). See [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle, Lifecycle Reference, Clean Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

The *"Why?"* is answered by [Mark O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29180108/1744774).

The answer to *"How to avoid?"* is: Don't delete your local repo completely.

You can delete sub-directories of libraries/artifacts you once tried out or tested but decided to abandon using them without any impact, though.